# Installed Ubuntu 12.04, Wireless connected but no internet

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:54:bd:2a:dd  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B) 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:32651 (32.6 KB)  TX bytes:32651 (32.6 KB) 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:d1:63:a6:40  
          inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::214:d1ff:fe63:a640/64 Scope:Link 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:563 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30352 (30.3 KB)  TX bytes:62116 (62.1 KB) 

dad@DAD:~$ iwconfig 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"CARZ2"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 28:10:7B:F2:D6:7A   
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off 
          Power Management:off 
          Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0 
          Tx excessive retries:21  Invalid misc:69   Missed beacon:0 

lo        no wireless extensions. 

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

dad@DAD:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            forcedeth
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:23:54:BD:2A:DD

  Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
  Carrier:         off
- Device: wlan0  [CARZ2] -------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rt2800pci
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:14:D1:63:A6:40

  Capabilities:
  Speed:           86 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
  WEP Encryption:  yes
  WPA Encryption:  yes
  WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
  ATT952:          Infra, 1C:14:48:56:FC:90, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 47 WPA WPA2
  betsy:           Infra, 5C:D9:98:6D:C8:26, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WPA
  vivien:          Infra, C0:C1:C0:8A:A3:8B, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA2
  ATT472:          Infra, 20:E5:64:B2:C6:A0, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
  ATT048:          Infra, 40:B7:F3:23:1F:20, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
  DH:              Infra, 30:46:9A:9B:D9:AE, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
  NETGEAR08:       Infra, 74:44:01:70:FE:66, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA2
  ATT400:          Infra, 20:E5:64:AC:2A:F0, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WPA WPA2
  B2B:             Infra, 74:31:70:0B:32:08, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2
  chowfunpoint:    Infra, AC:5D:10:19:02:A9, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA WPA2
  JIN-PC_Network:  Infra, 58:6D:8F:32:51:BC, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2
  TonyDang:        Infra, 00:26:82:F3:15:12, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2
  nhaai:           Infra, 94:0C:6D:EE:F7:EA, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA
  2WIRE218:        Infra, AC:5D:10:1C:9F:89, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WPA WPA2
  mckhome:         Infra, 74:9D:DC:E9:6D:B1, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WPA WPA2
  2WIRE894:        Infra, 28:16:2E:14:86:11, Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WPA WPA2
  ATT536:          Infra, 94:CC:B9:B9:3B:50, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WPA WPA2
  yilincao:        Infra, 00:24:C9:79:13:20, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WEP
  2WIRE862:        Infra, 00:1A:C4:9E:30:C9, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WEP
  2WIRE322:        Infra, 00:1E:C7:19:11:C1, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WEP
  2WIRE778:        Infra, 3C:EA:4F:83:69:C9, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WEP
  2WIRE764:        Infra, C0:83:0A:69:D7:C9, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WEP
  CP30:            Infra, F0:25:72:70:30:40, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WEP
  Pokemon:         Infra, 00:1C:F0:61:C1:43, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27
  ChinatownWiFi:   Infra, 00:0D:97:02:20:91, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 11 Mb/s, Strength 17
  *CARZ2:          Infra, 28:10:7B:F2:D6:7A, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 52 WPA WPA2
  Belkin_G_Wireless_CBA20B: Infra, 00:22:75:CB:A2:0B, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
  ClearSPOT_667b3: Infra, 00:1E:31:C6:67:B3, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WPA WPA2
  ATT184:          Infra, B0:77:AC:D9:55:A0, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
  ATT936:          Infra, 94:CC:B9:B7:DD:50, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 10 WPA WPA2
  2WIRE357:        Infra, B0:E7:54:DF:B8:41, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WEP
  agcaoili:        Infra, 98:2C:BE:5C:B2:89, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WEP

  IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         192.168.0.103
  Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
  Gateway:         192.168.0.1

  DNS:             192.168.0.1

dad@DAD:~$ ping -c3 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2016ms

Comment: you don't have a global ip, is the router connected to internet? Have you tried without a router?

Comment: May we see: nm-tool and also ping -c3 192.168.0.1

Comment: Alvar, Router is connected to the internet, All my other computers runs. I have windows running alongside this Ubuntu and they work fine. Ubuntu did not have any issue until I updated to 12.04. Thanks for the help!